# Number of solutions in a system for values a and b

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

In general, if you are given a system with some a and b like

$x + y + z = a $

$x + 2z= b$

$x + ay + z=b$

And asked to find the values a and b such that the system has no solution, infinitely many solutions, or a one solution what would be the constraints when row reducing the augmented matrix (ie you can't divide by something,  etc.).  For the problem above I did row operations on the augmented until I reached here

($ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & b \\ 0 & 1 & -2 & a-b \\ 0 & 0 & 2a & ab-a^2\\\end{matrix}$)

Comment: i got this here $$\left\{ x={\frac {2\,{a}^{2}-ab-b}{a-1}},y=-{\frac {a-b}{a-1}},z=-{
\frac {a \left( a-b \right) }{a-1}} \right\} 
$$

Comment: So then there would be no solution if a is one,  one solution if a and b were consistent with x, y, z l, but what about infinite solutions

Answer (score 0):

Do the row operation to the augmented matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & a \\
1 & 0 & 2 & b \\
1 & a & 1 & b \\
\end{bmatrix}
\sim \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & a \\
0 & -1 & 1 & b-a \\
0 & a-1 & 0 & b-a
\end{bmatrix}
\sim \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 & b \\
0 & -1 & 1 & b-a \\
0 & 0 & a-1 & a(b-a)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

From here, assuming $a-1\neq 0$ you can carry on row operations to get

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & b-\frac{2a}{a-1} (b-a)\\
0 & -1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{a-1}(b-a) \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{a}{a-1} (b-a)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If $a=1$ then you end up with

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 & b\\
0 & 1 & -1 & 1-b \\
0 & 0 & 0 & b-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So no solution.